# MYSQL X locks with transactions

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, pdo

Quick question,

I want to exclusive lock a row for a transaction eg:

`SELECT.....FROM.....FOR UPDATE`

my question is do I need to do this before doing `PDO::beginTransaction` -
Do the `UPDATE` inside the transaction and then manually unlock if an exception is thrown?

Or can I just have it inside the transaction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

calling `SELECT.....FROM.....FOR UPDATE` before PDO::beginTransaction doesn't make sense since it will be called in autowrapped transaction (if autocommit=true as by default in mysql) so no actual records will be locked.

So do it after beginTransaction

Comment: Well, I could change the autocommit. Just really wondering if there is any need to do this, or whether exclusive locking works fine within transactions, so no need for any funky business. Sorry kinda new to PDO and MYSQL..